# in react to reference component properties not defined as arguments?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
export default function SoftMount({
  children,
  child_ref,
  real_class_name,
  duration,
}) {
  
  return <div/>
}
```

usage:

```
<SoftMount unexpected_prop={"some_value"} />
```

Inside of `<SoftMount />`, how do I access `unexpected_prop`?

Comment: What’s `expected_prop`? Do you mean `unexpected_prop`?

Comment: yup, fixed in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture all remaining properties using the "rest parameters" sytax (`...variable_name`)

```
export default function SoftMount({
  children,
  child_ref,
  real_class_name,
  duration,
  ...other_props // This will collect all other props not destructured
}) {
  console.log(other_props.unexpected_prop); // "some_value"

  return <div/>
}
```